# Are stove top coil burners standard?

Tags: appliances, stove

I'm looking to replace my stove top coil burners, they are still working but are getting worn.

Las year I replace the over bottom element about a year ago, but back then I had a local repair shop and simply brought the old one to get the right kind, sadly this store is now closed.

I noticed the following inscription on the coil support.

8 inch
MP26YA
208/240 V
1855/2600W

6 inch
MP15YA
208/240 V
1130/1500 W

The connectors are quite standard.
The stove brand is "Frigidaire"

So what should I look for?
Is the brand important?

Comment: They should be quite easily available at most hardware/electric/even big box stores.

Comment: You'll want to make sure a new coil burner has the same diameter, number of turns, and W(att) rating as the one it replaces.

Answer (score 4):

For stock coil burners, (with just the two ends of the coil to connect by sliding into the mating part on the stove) they are quite interchangeable, at least in the US market. I have a "canning element" which I've used in 2 or 3 different electric stoves of different brands and models, with no problems.

When additional features and connections (temperature sensors, big coil around a small coil, etc.) are added they become considerably more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Are your burners just worn on their surfaces OR are they failing to heat or are they staying warm even when you have them turned off?

If the first is the case just get new OEM burner elements for your specific stove (specific mfgr and model) or get aftermarket ones that are referenced as a replacement for your make and model of stove. Personally if the coils are just a little worn, I would use them until they look like they are about to fail, but they are very, very easy to replace so if you don't like to look at worn coils, then . . .

If the latter two are the situation, the fault is almost certainly not in the coil elements, but rather in the surface burner control switches (aka infinite switches) inside behind the knobs. These switch/controllers are electro-mechanical devices with moving parts that suffer degradation over time and will eventually completely fail. You should investigate them as the source of the fault.

We have a 30-year-old GE coil top range and the burner controllers are worn so that they do not heat at all on the lower settings. The stove is still usable and we were just living with it. I was considering replacing some or all of the switches, but instead we are just using a counter-top induction unit set on the stove top to investigate whether we want to replace the range with an induction range. I pulled out the coil burners and have them in storage.

I just priced OEM surface burner control switches and they are $95 each so it would be $360 for all four plus shipping and sales tax. I think aftermarket controllers would be about 1/2 or 1/3 the price of OEM, but should I get aftermarket controllers made in an Asian sweatshop maybe in a country with an authoritarian government that is harassing our ships and planes and threatening to obliterate our base on Guam?

A friend gave me a burner control switch he removed from his electric range and that one has a small adjustment screw to calibrate it. Possibly I could just give a quarter turn in this screw on the units in my stove and recover the lower end. Of course it could be that screw was only to be used to calibrate a new switch and if I would adjust it on worn 30-year-old switches it would be ineffective or would damage the switches or even make them unsafe. Anyway, right now we are not using the switches but using two induction units placed on top of the GE range.